# Symfony2, Doctrine DQL, Subquery, get values from another table using a condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

As far as I know, doctrine dql does not allow subqueries inside a join.

I have a table and a trasnlation table. The relation is one to many. One record has many translations.

In order to get the right translation row from the translatiosn table I did subselects in the select clause:

```
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT w.id, w.pastid, w.name, w.jsonParameters as params, m.id as milestone_id, m.name as milestone_name,
                m.slug as milestone_slug, m.startdate as milestone_start, m.enddate as milestone_end, 
                w.expand as expand, w.backgroundcolor as background, w.colorschema as colorschema, w.headline as headline, w.subheadline as subheadline, w.text as text, w.expandheight as expandheight,  
                w.url as url, w.created as created, w.updated as updated, wt.name as wtname, ws.weight as width, ws.height as height
                , (SELECT t.headline FROM AdminBundle:widgetTranslation t WHERE t.widget = w.id and t.locale = :published) AS headline_trans
                , (SELECT t2.subheadline FROM AdminBundle:widgetTranslation t2 WHERE t2.widget = w.id and t2.locale = :published) AS subheadline_trans
                , (SELECT t3.text FROM AdminBundle:widgetTranslation t3 WHERE t3.widget = w.id and t3.locale = :published) AS text_trans
                FROM AdminBundle:Widget w
                JOIN w.milestone m
                JOIN w.widgetType wt
                JOIN w.widgetShape ws
                WHERE w.published = 1
                ORDER BY m.order, w.order
            ')->setParameter('published', $currentLocale);

        $result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

This query does the job but Iam worried about performance, is there a better query to do this?

Answer (score -1):

First, I need to clarify a little thing.
There is something **really wrong** in your question.
You are using an ORM, right? But you're talking about tables.
An ORM doesn't care about how your tables are organized or linked together. It only matters on the relationship between the objects themselves.

However, if you are worried about performance, the best thing to do, as you would do it with any SQL query, is to `EXPLAIN` it.

Since you're using Symfony 2.0, you may use the profiler (accessible in dev env) to see the `EXPLAIN` results of your query.

Make sure that is using index, and the number of rows to lookup is not too high.

Depending on your result you may need to use another strategy to fetch your translation or re-write your query in native SQL to allow more flexibility.

Comment: @Bart, and so what? If you go with the ORM approach you shouldn't worry about "the table" or "the database" this vocabulary has nothing to do with a ORM, the main purpose of an ORM is to abstract the persistance layer and provides an object mapping, may it come from a relational database, an xml document, a NoSQL server, etc. You can't use an hybrid solution 50% relational/50% objects, you either have to choose between one or other. Either use a Native SQL query or think about the relation between objects, not how they are represented in the persistance layer.

Comment: Whatever. You can call them "tables" (db terminology) or "collections" or whatever you like, but the relationships between those will remain the same, in this case a 1-to-many relation. I disagree on the strict separation of SQL from ORM however. How many times do you change the underlying system? In most cases never. Using ORM is usually more convenient when it comes to accessing properties and the like, however, writing a (native) SQL query can sometimes boost the performance of an otherwise slow part of your software by several orders of magnitude. End users won't care whether it's ORM/SQL.